# Managed-code action not changing property

Tags: c#, .net, dll, installation, installshield

I am attempting to use a managed code action in an InstallShield suite project.

I followed their example in hopes it wouldn't be a big deal.

http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield21helplib/helplibrary/SteActionManagedCd.htm

Ideally, I want to have my .dll method to change an install shield property when the action is executed. When I test out the installer to see if the property changed, I get the default value I set.

Maybe I am doing it wrong, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Web.Administration;

namespace IISHelp
{
  [Guid("BAFAEAED-08C6-4679-B94E-487A4D89DE63")]
  [TypeLibType(4288)]
  public interface ISuiteExtension
  {
    [DispId(1)]
    string get_Attribute(string bstrName);
    [DispId(2)]
    void LogInfo(string bstr);
    [DispId(3)]
    string get_Property(string bstrName);
    [DispId(3)]
    void set_Property(string bstrName, string bstrValue);
    [DispId(4)]
    string FormatProperty(string bstrValue);
    [DispId(5)]
    string ResolveString(string bstrStringId);
  }

 public class Help
 {
    const UInt32 ERROR_INSTALL_FAILURE = 1603;
    const UInt32 ERROR_SUCCESS = 0; 

    ISuiteExtension GetExtensionFromDispatch(object pDispatch)
    {
        if (Marshal.IsComObject(pDispatch) == false)
            throw new ContextMarshalException("Invalid dispatch object passed to CLR method");
        return (ISuiteExtension)pDispatch;
    }

    public UInt32 IsUniqueName(object pDispatch)
    {
        try
        {
            List<string> currentVirtualDirectories = GetApplicationNames();

            ISuiteExtension suiteExtension = GetExtensionFromDispatch(pDispatch);

            var name = suiteExtension.get_Property("APPLICATION_NAME");

            suiteExtension.set_Property("IS_UNIQUE_APPLICATION_NAME", (!currentVirtualDirectories.Contains(name)).ToString());
        }
        catch (System.ContextMarshalException)
        {
            return ERROR_INSTALL_FAILURE;
        }
        return ERROR_SUCCESS;
    }

    public List<string> GetApplicationNames()
    {
        List<string> currentVirtualDirectories = new List<string>();
        ServerManager mgr = new ServerManager();

        foreach (Site s in mgr.Sites)
        {
            foreach (Application app in s.Applications)
            {
                currentVirtualDirectories.Add(app.Path.Replace('/', ' ').Trim());
            }
        }
        return currentVirtualDirectories.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)).Distinct().ToList();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You'll need to say exactly where your CA is sequenced, and if it is deferred or not, and where in the install it is used (such as in the InstallExecute sequence).

Comment: As this is a suite, not an MSI, there is no "deferred", but scheduling is still relevant. Some form of logging, or even message box debugging, would probably work wonders to verify it's doing what you think. (From what is shown here, my guess is the suiteExtension isn't being set properly, but without visible traces. Or that the function is not even called. A `/debuglog` may tell more.)